# gain the y-axis value in python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I plot a figure with:

```
fig=plt.figure()
ax=fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(date,tso1.values)
```

How can I gain the figure's y-axis max and min values?
thank you.

Comment: what do you mean by 'gain'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if with "gain" you mean get, the answer is `ax.get_ylim()`.

A suggestion: I use ipython to inspect objects and the `help()` to understand what the methods do. On top of it, matplotlib method names tends to be very accurate. You can learn a lot about what you can do just playing with ipython and tab completion